# Checking if a completion is a @property in Jedi 0.14.0

Tags: python, autocomplete, python-jedi

We've recently upgraded the version of Jedi we are using from 0.13.2 to 0.14.0.

Previously, we could check whether an item in `Script.completions` was a `@property` by attempting to access its `param` attribute. If the completion was a property (or a regular attribute variable), then this would raise an `AttributeError`.

However, in version 0.14.0, no `AttributeError` is raised for properties.

I've worked around this by checking the source [as suggested here as a workaround for a similar issue](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1139#issuecomment-396580275):

```
if (completion.type == "function" and
        "@property" in completion.get_line_code(1)):
```

But this doesn't seem like a very clean solution.

Is there a better way of checking if a completion is a property in version 0.14.0?

Comment: What do you need this for? I'm really interested, because we could just add stuff like this natively.

Comment: @DaveHalter It's just so we know not to add `()` after the completion (which we do for functions).

Comment: Please open an issue in Jedi's issue tracker that describes your issue. Properties should not be type "function". That's the issue here.

Comment: @DaveHalter Okay, will do. Thanks!